# PyInstaller with Python-VLC: No Attribute "media_player_new" Error

Tags: python, dll, windows-10, pyinstaller, python-vlc

I'm using Python-VLC to create a video player and PyInstaller to generate the executable file on my Windows 10 machine. 
Initially, it gave me the error:

```
Import Error Failed to load dynlib/dll 'libvlc.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
```

To solve this issue, I added the missing dlls in the binaries of the .spec file in the following manner:

```
a = Analysis(['video_player.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\harsh\\Desktop\\demo\\Video'],
             binaries=[("C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\libvlc.dll","."),("C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\libvlccore.dll",".")],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

After doing this, I'm no more getting the above error. However, now I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 862, in run
  File "video_player.py", line 100, in vlc_player
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'
```

The code which leads to this error is:

```
i=vlc.Instance('--fullscreen')
p=i.media_player_new()
```

I've made sure that I've installed Python-VLC. Am I missing anything else here ?
Any suggestions on how to deal with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

One common answer to this problem is to make sure you have the VLC main programme installed, as the vlc.py relies on it. And also, that Python and the libvlc.dll both have to be 32-bit, or, both have to be 64-bit.